# Google AppEngine: how to allocate more money to budget

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

I created a GAE app before the budget changes that happend in november (-ish) 2011. I remember that at that time, when I enabled billing for the app, I've allocated a Balance of 50 euros. I'm not talking about the "Max Daily Budget" (which is set to 2.5 euros a day) but of the overall "Current Balance".

Currently, those initially allocated 50 euros have whiddled down to almost 0:

[image]

My question is: what do I need to do to re-add some money to that Balance ?

I've looked throgh the "Billing Settings" and "Billing History" panels in the GAE Console but I haven't found anything that would allow me to do this.

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can just add credit to you account as a one-off payment. Nor do I think you were ever able to.

Are you sure you didn't just get a $50 credit when it was leaving preview?
This is from an email I got from Google at the end of August last year:

> If you sign up for billing or update your budget between now and
>   October 31st we will give you a $50 credit.

Comment: Honestlly I don't remember that, but it sounds pretty plausible from what you're saying. At any rate, I'm now pretty sure that google will bill be as needed and I don't need to pre-allocate anything. Thanks

Comment: When the new pricing took effect, I rinsed through my $50 dollars in a few days... I wish my app was as cheap to run as yours!

Comment: Yeah well, when you have 10 visitors a day is pretty cheap:). Seriouslly, what helped somewhat was adding cache to the thing and enabling multithreading along with down-limiting resources such as max instances and increasing min serve time.